# Growing OS cache in RAM causing high system CPU usage

Tags: linux, memory, cache, cpu-usage

I'm having a weird issue with a server that I've never seen before. On a machine with ~30G of RAM with an application that takes ~10G (spread across hundreds of processes). Over time the OS starts to fill up the spare RAM with cache and buffers (totally normal for Linux). I've seen this happen before without any problems, but on this machine as the amount of empty RAM decreases it drives the system CPU crazy (100% across 8 CPUs for ~3 minutes) at about the 256M mark. I'm guessing the OS is using all that CPU to shuffle memory around to get some free space back.

From what I understand about Linux memory management it's supposed to use as much free space in RAM as it can for OS level caching but then give it over to any applications that need it when asked and from past experience this hasn't been a traumatic experience for the CPU. It happens all the time. So why could it be different here?

I'm attaching a small portion of the vmstat output for the related metrics (captured every 2 secs). You can see where the system CPU (14th column, 3rd from the right) starts getting busy when the free memory hits ~256M and then gets really crazy about 30 secs later.

```
r    b   swpd  free     buff     cache     si  so  bi   bo    in     cs     us  sy   id  wa
1    0   0     293876   5022848  18797528  0   0   206  1712  20924  12845  29  9    61  1
6    0   0     285324   5022848  18797656  0   0   0    0     18795  11382  23  9    68  0
2    0   0     292320   5022848  18797916  0   0   26   2022  19933  12068  27  10   62  1
3    0   0     264492   5022848  18798196  0   0   14   0     20705  15412  30  9    61  0
3    0   0     254880   5022848  18798804  0   0   190  532   16207  9723   31  8    60  0
17   0   0     255588   5021292  18783092  0   0   24   2     13521  7471   27  42   31  0
3    0   0     288396   5020536  18771496  0   0   0    2     14277  8458   24  29   47  0
4    0   0     299560   5020180  18761296  0   0   0    448   8778   5099   21  30   49  0
2    0   0     290908   5019376  18753656  0   0   0    2     9027   5115   27  19   54  0
7    0   0     306060   5018544  18746740  0   0   38   442   8398   5134   20  17   63  0
1    0   0     317140   5018244  18744252  0   0   46   0     9707   5822   22  17   61  0
4    0   0     282268   5017748  18741836  0   0   12   2     10203  6165   26  12   62  0
1    0   0     322548   5017500  18738024  0   0   2    444   10593  6277   23  16   61  0
4    0   0     314936   5017280  18734564  0   0   6    8     9473   5680   25  15   61  0
13   0   0     316976   5017044  18731128  0   0   0    622   12481  7353   33  17   49  0
5    0   0     324952   5016908  18728552  0   0   10   222   11071  6965   22  13   65  0
2    0   0     324692   5016908  18728344  0   0   0    526   10612  6602   24  10   66  0
3    0   0     312312   5017136  18727644  0   0   156  1050  12316  7472   26  10   63  1
2    1   0     323392   5017260  18726848  0   0   66   26    11643  7152   23  13   64  0
8    1   0     318956   5017124  18723772  0   0   20   518   17042  9543   31  22   46  1
1    0   0     317816   5017124  18725428  0   0   0    2854  11704  6951   21  9    67  3
18   0   0     325136   5014492  18707212  0   0   0    32    7619   3845   16  58   27  0
46   0   0     323508   5012980  18692036  0   0   0    562   3939   917    3   92   5   0
71   0   0     299164   5009680  18675476  0   0   0    6     4696   1304   8   90   1   0
75   0   0     205364   5007744  18657228  0   0   36   340   6699   2556   18  82   0   0
75   0   0     221660   5005956  18636480  0   0   68   0     3942   943    4   95   0   0
84   0   0     223788   5004624  18618380  0   0   0    0     2843   335    3   97   1   0
44   0   0     214956   5002464  18599872  0   0   0    0     4696   1301   5   92   3   0
37   0   0     223804   4999964  18577076  0   0   0    0     3281   521    1   98   0   0
82   0   0     266888   4995768  18557264  0   0   0    1760  4595   766    4   96   1   0
91   0   0     260148   4993964  18541192  0   0   0    0     3780   866    6   94   0   0
74   0   0     279796   4990464  18524980  0   0   0    4     4096   926    4   96   0   0
44   0   0     274796   4984268  18503492  0   0   0    0     6316   2142   3   95   3   0
48   0   0     295616   4981824  18482616  0   0   0    0     2561   227    1   99   1   0
```

I'm also including a screenshot from the monitoring tool to show more visually what's happening with the memory. In this graph, the bottom (purple) line is the actual free space left in RAM and everytime it reached 256M it causes a CPU spike.

[image]

BTW, swap is disabled on this machine (if you couldn't tell from the vmstats).

- Linux is 3.11.0, Ubuntu 13.10
- Not a Java application, it's PHP/Apache

Comment: What kernel version?

Comment: At first glance that seems the possible behaviour of Java garbage collection, running a java application?

Comment: Answers above. But as for the JVM GC issue, wouldn't that show up as a similar pattern with actual memory used? Unfortunately my monitoring system doesn't make it easy to see, but the actual application memory is the difference between the top 2 lines, which is pretty steady. The drastic cliffs are caused by the OS-cache, not the application memory.

Comment: This spits out a *lot* of data, but what is the output of `/proc/zoneinfo`

Comment: update to 14.04 and look if it is better, the 13.10 will be out of support soon.

Comment: I think Matthew Ife is suggesting that the behavior you see might be related to the "zone reclaim" issue.

Comment: I don't believe it's a zone reload problem. `cat /proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode` shows 0. Would it still make sense to capture the output of `/proc/zoneinfo` during a problem?

Comment: I'm no expert on this issue but it appears that even with the setting at 0 it can cause issues (see: http://rhaas.blogspot.ca/2014/04/subtly-bad-things-linux-may-be-doing-to.html). You haven't said what kind of application you're running but here is an attempt at a solution in the MySQL world (http://blog.jcole.us/2012/04/16/a-brief-update-on-numa-and-mysql/). Let me know if this is on the right track! I'll make it an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the leads, although I'm not sure they are panning out. I updated the question with the fact that it's a pretty standard Apache/PHP application. And I'm not sure about the zone reclaim problem because it seems that NUMA is off (`grep -i 'numa' /var/log/dmesg` gives `[0.000000] NUMA turned off`. It's a virtual machine running on AWS if that helps.

Comment: Also, `numactl --hardware` reports just a single node "0", so I doubt it's NUMA memory balancing problems.

Comment: Could it be kdmflush is active when you have the high CPU usage? Maybe you need to adjust vm.dirty_* tunables.

Answer (score 3):

I think the CPU is used just to scan the page tables to find which frames to free. It seems high though, I've got one system with small pages, 400 GB RAM and it doesn't show such dramatic behavior. Hard to say what is the root cause, but I'd like to propose a workaround.  Enable a substantial amount of huge pages (via `vm.nr_hugepages`). This would substantially  decrease the size of page tables, as huge page has 2 MiB, that is 512 times bigger than a small page. [This article describes a solution to a similar problem](http://www.pythian.com/blog/performance-tuning-hugepages-in-linux/).

One limitation is that huge pages are not swappable, but it does seem irrelevant in your situation.